# How do I create a group image of people, from individual images of each person?

Tags: image-generation

Our family is spread all over the world, and we're trying to create a single photo that looks like it was taken with all us of together in one room. I have separate photos of the different individual family members, and am trying to figure out how to create a single image.

I've played around with the various technologies out there I know of, but none of them seem to be able to composite an image together. Is there a technology I should be looking at?

UPDATE:
For example - the blend concept from Midjourney is not what I'm looking for.